# Differences between Swagger2 and JavaDoc

Tags: spring-boot, javadoc, swagger-2.0

I have a REST SpringBoot application with Swagger endpoints documentation.
But my teacher said use JavaDoc

Whats the differences JavaDoc and Swagger?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Swagger is for Rest API Documentation for e.g What is the API Signature Inputs and Outputs.

Please read https://swagger.io/resources/articles/documenting-apis-with-swagger/ for further information on Swagger

JavaDoc is for documenting your Code (Java Classes and methods).

Please read http://www.drjava.org/docs/user/ch10.html for further information on JavaDoc.